# Android EditText hint not center aligned on certain devices only

Tags: android

I have following layout:

[image]

[image]

The hint appears on top than it should be and only occurs at certain device only, such as Note 2 and S3.

My code:

**XML**

```
<MyEditText
    android:id="@+id/home_search_bar_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/home_search_bar_field"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/searchicon"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/home_search_text"
    android:textColorHint="@color/home_search_hint"
    android:hint="@string/search_bar_placeholder" />
```

**MyEditText**

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText implements OnTouchListener,
        OnFocusChangeListener{

    public interface Listener {
        void didClearText();
    }

    public void setListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    private Drawable xD;
    private Listener listener;

    public ClearableEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener l) {
        this.l = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnFocusChangeListener(OnFocusChangeListener f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    private OnTouchListener l;
    private OnFocusChangeListener f;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (getCompoundDrawables()[2] != null) {
            boolean tappedX = event.getX() > (getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - xD
                    .getIntrinsicWidth());
            if (tappedX) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    setText("");
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.didClearText();
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (l != null) {
            return l.onTouch(v, event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (f != null) {
            f.onFocusChange(v, hasFocus);
        }
    }

    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private boolean isNotEmpty(String text){
        return !text.isEmpty();
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        xD = getCompoundDrawables()[2];
        if (xD == null) {
            xD = getResources()
                    .getDrawable(android.R.drawable.presence_offline);
        }
        xD.setBounds(0, 0, xD.getIntrinsicWidth(), xD.getIntrinsicHeight());
        super.setOnTouchListener(this);
        super.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

What could be wrong in my code?

Comment: set android:gravity="start|center"

Comment: please provide full xml

Comment: I have solved it, please find my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it by removing:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Don't understand why by removing it, can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of edittext from match_parent to wrap_content.

```
android:height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

One more reason it can be that, the size of icon you are using in editext.

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/searchicon"
```

So, wrap_content will sort your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pre define the **layout_height**.
        Try this way

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:hint="test"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

Comment: U define layout_height of the view. it will be easy for you to align it

Comment: if u give match parent it will take entire screen(I hope this is not your requirement). if your requirement is to show the search box like above image, identify the search box height, how much it should be, then hard code it. Or else u can set wrap content and give padding and align it.